# bind variable does not exist with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am playing with dynamic sql and pl/sql and my idea is to create universal print procedure for rows of small size tables at least. In order the procedure to work I needed to find the values of certain columns so I involved dynamic sql. The function that finds the data has this code:

```
function find_value(p_table_name string, p_id_name string, p_id string, p_field string) 
return varchar2
as
rresult varchar2(50) := '';
query_str varchar2(200);
type cur_typ is ref cursor;
c cur_typ;
inv_num number;
begin
  query_str := 'select '||p_field||' from '||p_table_name||' where '||p_id_name||' = '||p_id;
  open c for query_str using inv_num;
  loop
    fetch c into rresult;
    exit when c%notfound;
  end loop;
  close c;
  return to_char(rresult);
end;
```

The error I get is:

> Error starting at line : 2 in command - BEGIN   --PROBNI_RED :=
>   JOB_PKG.GET_EMPLOYEE(100);
>   PPRINT.PRINT('EMPLOYEES','EMPLOYEE_ID',100); END; Error report -
>   ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist ORA-06512: at "ORA01.PPRINT",
>   line 14 ORA-06512: at "ORA01.PPRINT", line 44 ORA-06512: at line 3
>   01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I literally used dynamic SQL for the first time today, so I guess it can be something small.

Comment: I'd start with the code the error message points to (which you didn't include in your question)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I copied the whole error report.

Comment: Yes, and as I said, the error report points to code that you didn't include.

Comment: Be aware that by using dynamic sql in the way that you have (by not checking the column/table names meet the rules for identifier names (which you can do via [dbms_assert](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2)) and not using bind variables) left yourself wide open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). That's pretty bad in this day and age...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means your `using` clause told it to use `inv_num` but it has nowhere to use it. For example, this gives the error you are seeing:

```
declare
    some_var varchar2(1) := 'X';
begin
    execute immediate 'select * from dual' using some_var;
end;

ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

You would use a `using` clause with a bind variable like this:

```
declare
    some_var varchar2(1) := 'X';
begin
    execute immediate 'select * from dual where dummy = :b1' using some_var;
end;
```

Or you could pass a literal value:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'select * from dual where dummy = :b1' using 'X';
end;
```

(This demo doesn't actually do anything as it does not handle the output of the dynamic query - it's just to demonstrate the syntax.)

Note that binds like `:b1` in dynamic SQL are just positional placeholders and the names are not related to any variables or parameters in the calling PL/SQL, so naming them as if they are (e.g. `:p_id`) can cause confusion, even though the syntax is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use your variable `:p_id` in dynamic query

```
query_str := 'select '||p_field||' from '||p_table_name||' where '||p_id_name||' = :p_id';
```

if you want to use `using inv_num`

Answer (score 0):

I deleted

```
using inv_num;
```

And it started to work.